# How to remove y-axis values from google chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am using google charts.

In the attached image I do not want the 100, 50, 0, -50, -100 numbers to show.  But I do want the Satisfaction label to show.  Does anyone know how this can be achieved in google charts?  Is there and option on vAxis?

[image]

Another (less important) issue is that I only want the grid lines at 100, 0 and -100.  I do not want the other 6.

I currently have the following options set...

```
var options = {
    chartArea: { width: '80%' },
    colors: ['#00ff00', '#ff0000'],
    vAxis: {
        title: 'Satisfaction',
        maxValue: 100,
        minValue: -100,
        gridlines: { count: 2 }
    },
    legend: { position: 'bottom' }
};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the following vAxis option...

```
textPosition: 'none'
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y0', 'y1', 'y2'],
    [0, 10, 12, 18],
    [2, 16, 18, 19],
    [4, 18, 19, 24],
    [6, 26, 28, 22],
    [8, 13, 15, 21],
    [10, 32, 31, 33]
  ]);

  var options = {
    chartArea: { width: '80%' },
    colors: ['#00ff00', '#ff0000'],
    vAxis: {
      textPosition: 'none',
      title: 'Satisfaction',
      maxValue: 100,
      minValue: -100,
      gridlines: { count: 2 }
    },
    legend: { position: 'bottom' }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: WhiteHart - Great that fixed it.  Also I fixed my secondary issue with gridlines: { count: 2 },
                minorGridlines: { count: 0 }

Comment: great! glad you were able to resolve the gridlines, I missed that part of the question...

Comment: Great. It worked awesome. Even when I am generating the columns dynamically. I.e. when I don't know the type/data before executing the query. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. On the chart's configuration select "Gridlines and ticks".
2. On the first dropdown select vertical or horizontal axis, as you need.
3. On the "Major Spacing Type" dropdown select "Count".
4. On the "Major count" dropdown select "None".

That will make the values on the selected axis disappear.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the text color to white ? This will essentially make it look like the axis disappeared.

[image]